# Hunter pet not keeping aggro on some Timeless Isle mobs

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a level 90 hunter running around Timeless Isle for the past two weeks. I noticed that for some elite mobs, like the Death Adder, I get aggro just after three shots. My pet, with Growl set to auto-cast, can't seem to hold aggro on these elite mobs. I also noticed this occur on some of the rare elites that I happened upon solo. On other elite mobs, my pet keeps aggro fine.

I've Google'd my issue and saw quite a number of hunters experiencing the issue. Some said that there are some elite mobs that are untauntable. This goes against what some are saying that warlock pets hold aggro just fine. Unfortunately, I saw nothing official (from a moderator response, etc) regarding this issue.

Are some elite mobs in the Timeless Isle really untauntable? Or are hunter pets just bugged on some elite mobs in the Timeless Isle?

Comment: I would say this is a bug, that the hunter pet can't keep up aggro. Create a ticket to the GM's about this problem. If they don't have an answer the put it on to the testers to fix the bug. A pet should be able to keep the aggro, especially if you are taunting it. 

Tips I have for you.
attack the mob slowly allowing the pet to have time to attack and keep aggro,
use misdirecting shot on your pet for him to regain aggro without taunting.

Comment: @Wojtek'Charkz'Hordyniec I'll create a ticket the next time I log in and see if I can get any response.

Comment: You can just make the ticket on the wow website and get a chat with a gm in seconds when filling out what problem you have in the end you will have 3 choices, chat, ticket and call. Chat takes 1min on average to get a GM

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Glyph of misdirection which resets the cooldown on misdirection when used on your pet. If you continue to use misdirection, you can redirect all your agro to your pet. http://www.wowhead.com/item=42907/

Comment: I didn't ask for tips on what I can do to work around the issue. But yeah, I know about Misdirection, but you shouldn't have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some situations / mobs which ignores particular mechanics (taunt) or, for the sake of balance, hunter's pets are specially treated (e.g. rules for Avoidance).
Probably, the prime example is Brawler's Guild.

As a player who has both tanker (paladin) and hunter, I can confirm that some mobs are indeed untauntable.
Nevertheless, you can easily check is it indeed a bug or just "special mechanics". As a hunter, you have ability called Distraction Shot, which is a range taunt. If the mob appears to not response to Growl (pet's taunt), but does to Distraction Shot, we can assume it is most likely a bug.

Anyway, as a hunter, I find that pet can hold aggro in all situation quite fine (even when mobs are immune to taunt) if I'm in Beast Master specialization, have Blink Strikes as a talent and having Spirit Beast as a pet (simple because it gives mastery buff, which, as Beast Master hunter, increase pet damage which equals more threat from pet).

Answer (score 0):

Hunter pets do not growl on the 91-93 Elite mobs on the Timeless Isle. You have to manually make them growl and then all is well.